# Portal 2 Peer Review DLC didn't download

Tags: ps3, portal-2, portal-2-peer-review

I have downloaded the Portal 2 DLC from the PSN and then installed the DLC onto my system.

When I go to play the game, the only new thing in any of the menus is "Download Free DLC" in the main menu. When I choose that, it says "there are no new items to purchase". When I go into co-op, the new area that is supposed to be open is not. I have completed both the single player and co-op parts of the game.

Anyone have any idea why I can't access the DLC?

Comment: Are you completely sure that you and/or your partner in science has completed all the co-op levels 100%?